# Is there a translation-invariant way to assign probabilities to infinite subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

There is no uniform probability distribution over the integers.  But I’m wondering whether the next best thing can be constructed.  My question is, is there a meaningful way to assign probabilities to (some) infinite subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ which is translation-invariant?

I’m thinking asymptotic density, though I’m not sure if that’s translation-invariant or not.

Comment: Asymptotic density is finitely additive and translation-invariant; see [this PDF](https://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/talks/PROB.pdf).

Comment: You can also define finitely additive, translation invariant probability "measures" on all subsets of $\mathbb Z$ using [Banach limits](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Banach_limit), but these are not explicitly constructible (they require some form of the Axiom of Choice)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks, great minds think alike, the two-envelopes paradox was exactly the context that motivated this question.  Can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: Done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asymptotic density is finitely additive and translation-invariant; see [this PDF](https://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/talks/PROB.pdf), for instance.